# How to use awk to chop pattern in a line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have multiple lines in a file like this:

```
u_top/cell_u0/Y (INV)  
u_top/cell_u3/A (AND)  
u_top/cell_u32/B (BUF)
```

Idea is to insert "`size_cell`" in front of each line, chop the last slash and characters right after it i.e "`/Y`", chop parenthesis.
I want to reformat it to the following:

```
size_cell u_top/cell_u0 INV  
size_cell u_top/cell_u3 AND  
size_cell u_top/cell_u32 BUF
```

Comment: You might try adding `awk` and `sed` tags - and showing what you have managed so far.

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer. @bryan

Answer (score 1):

One liner

```
awk -F' ?[()]' '{sub(/\/[^/]*$/,"",$1)}$1="size_cell" OFS $1' file
```

Or:

```
awk -F'/[^/]* *[(]|[)]' '$1="size_cell" OFS $1' file
```

work for your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$0="size_cell " $0} {split($2,a,"/"); $2=a[1] "/" a[2] ;gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$3)}1' tag
size_cell u_top/cell_u0 INV
size_cell u_top/cell_u3 AND
size_cell u_top/cell_u32 BUF
```